# A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property while Creating XML data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following Code.  I want insert data UserName and Password in SQL database using XML Element. But its Showing error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property

Also I have mention my expected output.

I have tried to result with:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
XElement ele = new XElement("Element", new XElement("UserId", strUserName), new XElement("Password", strPassword));
```

But I am not able to access strUserName and strPassword.:

suppose i pass hard coded user name & password it's working fine.

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
XElement ele = new XElement("Element", new XElement("UserId", "admin"), new XElement("Password", "admin"));
```

Comment: Move your logic **inside** a function.

Comment: Thanku @mjwills

Comment: [I've answered a similar question today....](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53140572/3094533)