# a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to work with .Net C# and Azure blob storage

I follow Microsoft's documentation in order to access a blob table.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class EmailAdress
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
            new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(
                "experimentstables", "token"), true);

        // Create the table client.
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        // Get a reference to a table named "peopleTable"
        CloudTable pexperimentsEmailAddresses = tableClient.GetTableReference("experimentsEmailAddresses");
    }
}
```

in this line

```
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
```

storageAccount is marked red with the following error:

> a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property

How should I fix it?

Comment: Why do you write your code inside class? Make some method or constructor and write your code there.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `storageAccount` and `tableClient` as class members, so `storageAccount` has to be `static` in order to use it

```
public class EmailAdress
{
    static CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(...);
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
}
```

Or you can put the initialization inside method.

Answer (score 1):

Create a constructor and implement all your field initializations there.

```
public class EmailAdress
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
    CloudTableClient tableClient;
    CloudTable pexperimentsEmailAddresses;

    public EmailAdress()
    {
        storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
        new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(
            "experimentstables", "token"), true);

        // Create the table client.
        tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        // Get a reference to a table named "peopleTable"
        pexperimentsEmailAddresses = tableClient.GetTableReference("experimentsEmailAddresses");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [c# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#instance-field-initialization) clearly states:

> A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created. Thus, it is a compile-time error to reference this in a variable initializer, as it is a compile-time error for a variable initializer to reference any instance member through a simple_name.

You can initialize a field with respect to another field only in a constructor.

**Will not compile:**

```
class A
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = x + 1;        // Error, reference to instance member of this
}
```

**Will compile:**

```
class A
{
    public A() 
    {
        int x = 1;
        int y = x + 1;        // Works just fine
    }
}
```